# Weblogic throws CompilationException

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, weblogic

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException: Failed to compile JSP /WEB-INF/content/intro.jsp
messages.tag:2:30: The encoding specified on the page cannot be different than detected encoding for the file.
<%@ tag body-content="empty" pageEncoding="utf-8" %>
                             ^----------^
```

If I remove pageEncoding attribute in tag file, it works. But I think this is not a solution, because it already works on another Weblogic server. So the problem is with my Weblogic configuration. By Googling the error, I did not found anything.

Any ideas? I have tried setting encoding to UTF-8 in weblogic.xml and many other things I can't even remember, I have had this issue for some time now.

Answer (score 2):

*WebLogic* expects strict encoding. So add the *page encoding tag* as the first declaration before any other declarations in the jsp. It solved the problem for me.

From:

`<%@ page import="com.abc.xyz.Helperjsp"%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8" %>`

To:

`<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8" %>
<%@ page import="com.abc.xyz.Helperjsp"%>`

Comment: It's more than just rearranging those two lines. Actually, it's not even a rearrangement, but more like moving that directive to the very top of everything else. The JSP directive containing the `pageEncoding` **MUST BE the very first thing in the file**. That means you cannot have JSP blocks, JSP directives, JSP comments or anything before that.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the contents of /WEB-INF/content/intro.jsp are also UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: They are. Problem is with the Weblogic configuration, not with the application.

Comment: @Enno: Are they correct before or after the FTP transfer to the server host?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on KarthikN's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5190503/1134080) and my own [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141410/weblogic-throws-compilationexception#comment43313467_5190503).

It must be noted that the important point is that the directive containing the `pageEncoding` **must be the first declaration** on your JSP page. As stated in my comment:

> It's more than just rearranging those two lines. Actually, it's not even a rearrangement, but more like moving that directive to the very top of everything else. [...] That means you cannot have JSP blocks, JSP directives, JSP comments or anything before that.

For example, if your existing JSP page that gives you the error is:

```
<%-- Some JSP comment --%>
<% /* (OR) Some Java comment in JSP block */ %>
<%@ page import="com.abc.xyz.Helperjsp"%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8" %>
```

I misunderstood KarthikN's example and simply swapped the two lines. It **did not work:**

```
<%-- Some JSP comment --%>
<% /* (OR) Some Java comment in JSP block */ %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8" %>
<%@ page import="com.abc.xyz.Helperjsp"%>
```

When the directive was placed above everything else, it **worked:**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8" %>
<%-- Some JSP comment --%>
<% /* (OR) Some Java comment in JSP block */ %>
<%@ page import="com.abc.xyz.Helperjsp"%>
```

Although KarthikN's answer mentions this (*"add the page encoding tag as the first declaration before any other declarations in the jsp"*), the example provided doesn't make it clear.